# What volatility estimator for continuous data and small time window?

Tags: volatility, estimation, high-frequency-estimators

I want to know which volatility estimator should I use for the following scenario:

I am implementing a market making bot and therefore I need to make estimations of the volatility of the price in the fashion of asking: What was the volatility of the price in the last couple of Minutes? (5-30 Minutes)

The data I've got available for the estimation is a set of all the prices in that time period at an interval of about 2-5 seconds, which are about 500 data point. And every time a new data point is added to the set, all data points that are older than the period of interest (5-30 Minutes) are removed from it.

Right now I use a basic estimator that calculates the variance of all the prices, however the problem with that is: the volatility oscillates way to much. I would expect the volatility to change slow and continuous over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use an exponential moving average, since the amount of state you need to keep is much smaller than for a simple moving average.

Second the well known estimator of volatility,

$$
\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
$$

is not very robust, since the squaring amplifies the contribution of outliers (which is why you are observing a very noisy volatility estimate - high frequency data has a *lot* of outliers).

Instead, consider using a mean absolute deviation estimate,

$$
\hat{\sigma}_{MAD} =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - \bar{x}|
$$

which is more robust to outliers. You need to multiply this by a factor of $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ so that it matches the scale of the standard deviation estimator above.

The quantities $x_i$ should be the price differences from tick to tick, i.e.

$$
x_i = p_i - p_{i-1}
$$

or maybe the returns,

$$
x_i = \frac{p_i}{p_{i-1}} - 1
$$

You might want to consider thresholding the $x_i$ to some maximum value, say 5x or 10x the current volatility estimate, to reduce the impact of outliers even further.

Comment: In the lecture I have about the market making algorithm I use, they propose the estimator by Garman and Klass. What do you think about that ?

Comment: Garman Klass is a classical well known estimator, but perhaps not specifically developed for such short term data (was developed for daily OHLC, I believe). Bur probably OK to use.

Comment: From the lecture I talked about: "A second approach is to use the estimator proposed by Garman and Klass [60] (orig-
inally devised for volatility across different days) adapted to the case of a time window
of several minutes." Do you think Garman and Klass would fit even better here ?

Comment: @Chris Taylor You say I need to calculate the moving average. Do you mean MA like a smoothed graph? Because in the formula you gave me the average has no index i so I assumed I need to calculate the average of all values over the whole time window?!

Comment: No, you can compute a moving average of returns (though to be honest, this will be so close to zero most of the time that you might as well use $\bar{x} = 0$).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Is it normal to calculate the standard deviation of the return when we speak about the volatility. I assumed I need to compute the standard deviation of the actual price. In the former case it totally makes sense to assume the average is 0. Still I am not quite sure what you mean with moving average. The average of the time window or  like a smoothed curve, which I then use to subtract the value of the smoothed curve from each corresponding datapoint.   Thanks for your effort btw

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I spent my evening learning about EWMA and I think I get what you say now. You mean I should use EWMA in the first place, but when I use a simple moving window estimation I should use the second estimator rather than first one. Did I get that right now ? lol